# iOS App name for iTunes and name which will be displayed on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I have a very short question. Should them match or not?

If I have name in iTunes for example:

```
 Notes+ - the best and professional way to display and manage your notes
```

Should I display the same on the device? Or It can be only:

```
 Notes+
```

I see a lot of apps which uses a short name on the device but long on iTunes. But  I guess few months ago one of my apps was rejected with reason that names do not match. After that, I always put the same name on the device and iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be different, and most often it is, for instance, the name on the AppStore is searchable so your app can be found by searching for "manage your notes".
The app "Fooducate" shows on your iPhone as "Fooducate" and in the AppStore it is "Weight Loss Coach by Fooducate - Personalized Calorie Counter, Food Tracker, Motivation, and Healthy Recipes"

Comment: Just came in from Apple via email: 
"Search is one of the most frequently used methods for customers to discover and download apps from the App Store. In hopes of influencing search results, some developers have used extremely long app names which include descriptions and terms not directly related to their app. These long names are not fully displayed on the App Store and provide no user value. App names you submit in iTunes Connect for new apps and updates will now be limited to no longer than 50 characters."